# Shell script to list all files in a folder on a single line

Tags: shell, files, command

I have this folder structure:

```
/Brand/ProductCode01
/Brand/ProductCode02
```

[image]

Each ProductCode## folder contains many JPG files, like

`image01.jpg, image02.jpg` and so on

I need to create a file that contains a single line for each ProductCode that lists all the files that exist in the folder "ProductCode##", like:

```
/Brand/ProductCode01/image01.jpg /Brand/ProductCode01/image02.jpg /Brand/ProductCode01/image03.jpg
/Brand/ProductCode02/image01.jpg /Brand/ProductCode02/image02.jpg
```

All the files need to be listed on a single line, separated by space and ended with newline at the last filename.

Any suggestions?

Thank You.

Comment: Do you want linux newline or windows {carriage return + newline} at the end? Or something else?

Comment: I need Linux newline

Comment: Better use `tree` command than taking pictures... My post is edited accordingly

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Answer (score 2):

**[Don't confuse CR-LF and LF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)!** AKA ***C**arriage **R**eturn* and ***L**ine **F**eed*

Like this:

```
$ tree
.
└── Brand
    └── Ducati
        ├── A 1060
        │   ├── image01.jpg
        │   └── image02.jpg
        ├── A 1061
        │   ├── image01.jpg
        │   └── image02.jpg
        ├── A 1062
        │   ├── image01.jpg
        │   └── image02.jpg
        └── A 1063
            ├── image01.jpg
            └── image02.jpg

6 directories, 8 files
```

```
$ for d in ./Brand/Ducati/A*/; do echo "$d"image*.jpg; done | tee file.txt
./Brand/Ducati/A 1060/image01.jpg ./Brand/Ducati/A 1060/image02.jpg
./Brand/Ducati/A 1061/image01.jpg ./Brand/Ducati/A 1061/image02.jpg
./Brand/Ducati/A 1062/image01.jpg ./Brand/Ducati/A 1062/image02.jpg
./Brand/Ducati/A 1063/image01.jpg ./Brand/Ducati/A 1063/image02.jpg
```

Works both in `bash` and `zsh` and probably `ksh` and bourne like shells.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`:

```
{
  for dir ( /Brand/ProductCode<->(Nn/) )
    () {print -rC1 -- "$*"} $dir/image<->.jpg(Nn)
} > your-file.txt
```

Or for directories (`/` glob qualifier) with any names inside `/Brand`, and all *regular* files (`.` qualifier) within them recursively (still sorted `n`umerically with the `n` glob qualifier):

```
{
  for dir ( /Brand/*(Nn/) )
    () {printf -rC1 -- "$*"} $dir/**/*(Nn.)
} > your-file.txt
```

Not that since newline (or space which you use as separator here) is as valid a character as any in a  file paths, you could still get more than one line per brand.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with

```
for i in /Brand/Ducati/*/; do ( find "$i" -type f | sed -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/"| tr '\n' ' '|sed "s/ $/\n/" ); done
```

- All file names (in the directory trees of /Brand/Ducati/subdirs/ ) will be listed (one set of lines for each subdir)
- a quote will be put before and after each file name (in order to manage file names with spaces and other special characters later on)
- newlines will be converted to spaces
- the last space in each line will be converted to newline

Comment: Is there any way to use a single command line for all folders inside /Brand? I tried /Brand/*/ but it doesn't works, it generate a single line only

Comment: I tested the current command line on a directory structure that I think matches what you show in the picture in the question, and it works there. You must explain with enough detail what you have and what you want, otherwise it will be difficult to help you. - I ***think*** that it would work if you replace 'Ducati' with an asterisk: `for i in /Brand/*/*/; do ...` for the case that you ask for now.

Answer (score -1):

```
ls -1 | tr '\n' ' '
```

See also the -q and -b flags.

Comment: This will only show the files in the current directory, not the variously-located files the question is looking for.